# Purchase non-consumable in app feature multiple times

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

not sure if this pass as a Stackoverflow question (close if not).

The problem we're facing at the moment is we have an app that we want to allow user to pay to unlock additional content space so they can create more content but be able to purchase multiple copies of that item without being charged twice unless they've exceeded what they've initially purchased.

So a concrete example is this:

Think of a item bag in World of Warcraft that lets user carry more items. (Our app isn't a game but it's the same concept). Users can buy many copies of the bag and at the same time, it doesn't matter if the user log into the app from their home computer or another computer, the bags are still tied to their account.

I'm aware that I have two options really:

### Non-Cosumable In App Purchase

- User buys the in app purchase item once but does not buy another copy. In other words, they can only ever have 1 copy of that item, not 10 or 20 copies (which our business logic requires in this case).

### Consumable In App Purchase

- Allows purchasing multiple copies of the item BUT they are non-transferable purchases. This would mean users would need to pay for the same item again even if they bought a new iPad, they can't transfer those "bags" to the new iPad or if they delete the app and reinstall the app, they would still need to pay for those items again.

Subscription based in app purchase doesn't exactly fit our model.

So is there a special type of non-consumable in app purchase but allows the user to buy multiple copies of that item/feature?

### Additional Considerations

- We do not have a third party server to track users and the number of copies of that item/feature they unlocked.
- It also doesn't make sense to make a hundred copies of the in app purchase in iTunes Connect manually.

I think only making a consumable in app purchase is our only option. We're reluctant to force to user to have to pay for unlocking the same content twice but at the same time don't want users to be able to keep creating additional "bags" for free.

Comment: Consumable IAP is the way to go for you. But, as you have mentioned, you should have server to keep the track of the items user purchased/spent for your users to have better experience in cases when your user has multiple devices, reinstalled app, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If user purchases a non-consumable purchase twice, I am sure Apple store has mechanism to prevent the purchase.

Instead, it would simply say: *You have already purchased this product. It will be downloaded again.* You will get all the delegates being called normally, and content delivery will happen as per what you have coded, but the customer will not be charged.

To avoid the payment flow, you can store the purchased item under itunes user's keychain, too.

Comment: Yes it does. Appstore would say "You have already purchased this. Do you want to purchase this again for free?" essentially at this point it just triggers another restore "like" process but through the normal Payment queue. Essentially, it will work if there is only 1 Buy button in your app since it would act both like Buy and Restore, but apple Specifically mentions that both Buy and Restore buttons should be present in the app. Why? not sure, may be to not confuse the user, or something.